# Trying to Find a 'Weird Tales/DarkSide' TYPE Episode seen 1980s

Tags: story-identification, tv

Sometime from about 1986-89 , I saw a 'Weird Tales' type TV Episode, and I have never been able to find it again after seeing it that one time. It was REALLY Cool and Twisted- And I have looked thru the descriptions of Every Anthology type Series on back then I can find, Tales for the Darkside, etc Etc. And I just can't find a clue, lol. It was a Story about this Televangelist, who was dirty,rich and intent on being richer,etc etc, all while professing his Godliness lol,  like so many are, and was an ahole to everyone, etc. And one night after his show, He said or did something,made a claim, or promise, whatever, that he would do something, etc, if 'God' told him to or something along those lines. And he goes into his office, and next thing you know,BAM... The LORD Has Come for the Appointment, Lol... And SHE Isn't Happy, and you see the Door swingin shut, and then after a bit, he assistant peeks in on him, and he's on his knees, teary eyed, hair a mess, and mumbling to himself about 'Changing things', And then the last Scenes are Him going back on the Air, and sorta like in the Howling, He starts SPITTIN TRUTH- REAL TRUTH, and Thats all I can remember. It stopped me in my tracks at the time, and I'm not even religious, Lol, tho it wasn't really THAT, but more the Dudes Hypocrisy and stuff. I may have some of the details wrong, hell, its pushin 40 years since I saw it, but I've NEVER seen it again, and would LOVE to know WHAT It was, and where I could find it again ! Well, Thanks in advance, All !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tales_from_the_Darkside_episodes - The Unhappy Medium had a televangelist, but the rest of the plot is nothing like what you're describing